# CentOS 7 Default Route for Static IP on Two Interface

Tags: networking, centos

I have a server with two interfaces(em1 and em2). When the network comes up it sets the default route to em2:

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em2
192.168.2.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em1
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 em1
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 em2
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em2

# cat ifcfg-em1
TYPE=Ethernet
NAME=em1
DEVICE=em1
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
UUID=1*********************
IPV6INIT=no
MTU=15000
IPADDR=192.168.2.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.2.1
NM_CONTROLLED="no"

# cat ifcfg-em2
TYPE=Ethernet
NAME=em2
DEVICE=em2
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
UUID=2*********************
IPV6INIT=no
MTU=15000
IPADDR=192.168.1.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
```

**How can I get the default route to be set on em1 instead of em2?**

Answer (score 3):

Simply set the `DEFROUTE` directive to `yes` on the interface that you want to be the default gateway. So:

```
DEFROUTE=yes
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a much better solution than my answer was... think I might just go and delete mine... :)

Comment: Didn't work. CentOS 7 - two interfaces. One with DEFROUTE=yes and it's still picking the other interface.

Comment: I had to change ONBOOT=no on em2 to get em1 to be default.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so interfaces are superceded by network routes. To change the default normally in CentOS 7 to route out a selected interface regardless of its order.

Verify/edit the following file:
/etc/sysconfig/network
GATEWAY=192.168.2.1
GATEWAYDEV=em1
NETWORKING=YES

Of course there are other ways to do this as well as additional entries to this file but this will infact get you your desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

On my CentOS 7 minimal I had to set the following in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` for my primary interface `eth0` to have the default route:

```
DEFROUTE=yes
```

And for the other (secondary) interface `eth1` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1` explicitly the other way around:

```
DEFROUTE=no
```

That way, it's possible to set `ONBOOT=yes` for both interfaces being enabled right after boot and being configured correctly :)